# Sql Multiple Join Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I saw some code that does this...

```
select *
from A 
left join B
left Join C
on C.column1 = B.column3
on B.column2 = A.column4
and C.column5 > 0
and B.column6 < 0
```

is this equivalent to

```
select *
from A 
left join B

on B.column2 = A.column4
and B.column6  < 0

left Join C
on C.column1 = B.column
and C.column5 > 0
```

Why would anyone ever do that first snippet? was it maybe a typo?

Comment: The first code posted appears to be invalid. Trivially (ignoring the semantic structure) [there is only one ON clause (or `join_condition`) allowed per JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has a looser syntax for joins than the ANSI standard.  In fact, there is a whole section of the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) devoted just to this topic.

The first query is indeed acceptable syntax, as shown in this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63e586/1).  This query (same query, different formatting):

```
select *
from A left join 
     B left Join
     C
     on C.column1 = B.column3
     on B.column2 = A.column4 and C.column5 > 0 and B.column6 < 0
```

Is interpreted as if there were parentheses:

```
select *
from A left join 
     (B left Join
      C
      on C.column1 = B.column3
     )
     on B.column2 = A.column4 and C.column5 > 0 and B.column6 < 0;
```

You can perhaps convince yourself of this by swapping the `on` clauses.  This query:

```
select *
from A left join 
     B left Join
     C
     on B.column2 = A.column4 and C.column5 > 0 and B.column6 < 0
     on C.column1 = B.column3;
```

produces an error.  The `A` table reference is not known for the first `on` clause, because that join is just between `B` and `C`.

I'm not sure why someone would do it.  It could be that the parentheses were dropped in some "clean-up" phase.  It could simply be that when writing the query, this syntax made sense and the person never noticed how awkward the query is (as a note:  *I've* *never* done such a thing ;).  It could be intentional obfuscation.